# efficiently construct a "switch" statement within a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's a minimalistic view of my problem (removing all unnecessary details). Essentially, it is an "assembly code" executor:

```
while(self.pc < len(self.memory)):
  instruction = [int(i) for i in str(self.memory[self.pc])]

  #simulated "switch" statement.
  def switch(Opcode):
    op1 = getOperand(instruction[1], instruction[2])
    op2 = getOperand(instruction[3], instruction[4])
    def add():
      if op1['mode'] = self.modes['gpr']:
        self.gpr[op1['gpr']] = op1['opValue'] + op2['opValue']
      else:
        self.memory[op1['opAddress']] = op1['opValue'] + op2['opValue']
      self.clock += self.clockSpeed['add']
    def subtract():
      if op1['mode'] = self.modes['gpr']:
        self.gpr[op1['gpr']] = op1['opValue'] - op2['opValue']
      else:
        self.memory[op1['opAddress']] = op1['opValue'] - op2['opValue']
      self.clock += self.clockSpeed['subtract']
    def invalid():
      raise ValueError('invalid Opcode in instruction: {}'.format(instruction) 
    return {
      0: add,
      1: subtract,
      "invalid": invalid
    }.get(Opcode, "invalid")()

  switch(instruction[0])
  self.pc += 1
```

when I run this program with a simple array of around 40 elements (slightly more complicated method, but not much more) using the `timeit module`, it does take quite some time:

```
print 'timing execution of execute: ', timeit.timeit('vm.CPUexecuteProgram()', setup="from __main__ import OS; vm=OS(); vm.AbsoluteLoader('../assembly_code/assemble_code.exe')")
```

`timing execution of execute:  0.673621892929`

I believe that the definition is "re-making" itself on every iteration. Would there be a more efficient way which would follow the same "pattern" shown here? I'd like to avoid using if/elif/else if possible, to make it more readable.

Comment: a `dict` with function references or lambda references can be a nice substitute for `switch` in Python

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if op1['mode'] = self.modes['gpr']:
```

Needs to be:

```
if op1['mode'] == self.modes['gpr']:
```

For all of your comparisons. The double-equal is "does left equal right?". The single equal is "assign right to left, then return right".

Comment: aye, I didn't run this code, though. This is just an approximation of what I am doing currently (to cut out a lot of the stuff no one cares about... there's twenty ops and 6 modes)

Comment: Oh, gotcha. So this was just a typo in coming up with demo code?

Comment: yep, my actual program does what it is supposed to do and yields expected results, it just does it... less than efficiently. Although things work, almost a second for forty instructions does not seem scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you code creates all the functions and the entire dictionary on every instruction. In your real code (assuming 40 distinct opcodes), this means at least 42 object instantiations (1 per opcode, `switch`, the dict) per instruction executed. You can simply pull the loop-invariant parts (creation of `add`, `sub`, ...; creation of the opcode->function dict) out of the loop, make `op1` and `op2` parameters, and reduce the loop to this:

```
while self.pc < len(self.memory):
    instruction = ...
    op1 = ...
    op2 = ...
    implementations[instruction](op1, op2)
    self.pc += 1
```

That should shave off a considerable fraction of the time. There are probably other places where one can optimize a bit, but since that isn't your real code and it's quite sloppy (several syntax errors, some parts look wrong) I will refrain from guessing.

Comment: actually, I did try this solution first. However, it did not amount to any better timeit time. `timing execution of execute:  0.803081989288`
Theoritically, if you do `switch()` as a method at all, wouldn't it have to instantiate all of the child methods every time, even if you call it outside the loop?

Comment: @crow There is no place for switch(), at most for make_dict(). Since the timing you give is *worse* than the version in the question, I suspect you did something different than what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange it:

```
def add(op1, op2):
  if op1['mode'] = self.modes['gpr']:
    self.gpr[op1['gpr']] = op1['opValue'] + op2['opValue']
  else:
    self.memory[op1['opAddress']] = op1['opValue'] + op2['opValue']
  self.clock += self.clockSpeed['add']

def subtract(op1, op2):
  if op1['mode'] = self.modes['gpr']:
    self.gpr[op1['gpr']] = op1['opValue'] - op2['opValue']
  else:
    self.memory[op1['opAddress']] = op1['opValue'] - op2['opValue']
  self.clock += self.clockSpeed['subtract']

def invalid(op1, op2):
  raise ValueError('invalid Opcode in instruction: {}'.format(instruction)

switch = {0: add, 1: subtract} 
while (self.pc < len(self.memory)):
  instruction = [int(i) for i in str(self.memory[self.pc])]
  Opcode = instruction[0]

  op1 = getOperand(instruction[1], instruction[2])
  op2 = getOperand(instruction[3], instruction[4])
  switch.get(Opcode, invalid)(op1, op2)
  self.pc += 1
```

this way it won't redefine all the methods every time.

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator

class Something(object):
    _operations =  {
        0: lambda self, instruction: self._execute("add", instruction),
        1: lambda self, instruction: self._execute("subtract", instruction),
        "invalid": lambda self, instruction: self_invalid(instruction)
        }
    _operators = {
        "add": operator.add,
        "substract": operator.sub
        }

    def _execute(self, operation, instruction):
        op1 = getOperand(instruction[1], instruction[2])
        op2 = getOperand(instruction[3], instruction[4])
        operator = self._operators[operation]
        val = operator(op1, op2)
        if op1['mode'] == self.modes['gpr']:
            self.gpr[op1['gpr']] = val
        else:
            self.memory[op1['opAddress']] = val
        self.clock += self.clockSpeed[operation]

    def _invalid(self, instruction):
        raise ValueError(
            'invalid Opcode in instruction: {}'.format(instruction)
            )

    def _switch(self, instruction):
        return self._operations.get(instruction[0], self._invalid)(self, instruction)

    def whatever(self):
        while self.pc < len(self.memory):
            instruction = [int(i) for i in str(self.memory[self.pc])]
            self._switch(instruction)
            self.pc += 1
```